# NodeJS | module.js:540 throw err

Tags: javascript, node.js

So it's the first ever program I write but when I run it in the console I get this error.

```
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\app'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

I have no idea why this is happening as I am new but I checked the code and nothing is wrong.

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
    res.end('Hello World!');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port '+port);
});
```

Comment: Where is this project located and what command did you use to run the application?

Comment: It seems like the script you wanted to execute isn't named "app". What command did you use and whats the name of your file?

Comment: Omg, How could I miss that.

Comment: How do I mark as solved

Comment: You can't mark it as solved without an answer. But if the name was indeed the reason I can post it as an answer

Comment: See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800#62740853](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800#62740853).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582 throw err](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545800/internal-modules-cjs-loader-js582-throw-err)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the script you wanted to execute isn't named "app".

Check the Path and name of your script when you execute it with the `node` command.